# Where is data located in usb debugging mode Android

Tags: android, database, local-storage

I have written an app which basically inputs data into a database which is saved in the same folder as the app itself. I have used MODE_PRIVATE for this. I am using USB Debugging mode with Android Studio and my Phone. It is obvious to me that the database is stored somewhere inside my phone but I cannot seem to locate it.

Any ideas? Is it due to the private mode I set, or because of USB Debugging, or maybe I'm not searching hard enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database is created somewhere inside of your app's private folder, which is usually (but now always!) located in /data/data/your_package_name>/files. In newer versions of Android, some data might be created in the external folder (either /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/ or /storage/emulated/...Android/data/your_package_name/).

However, in most cases you can't access your application's private files via USB debugging unless you're using an Android emulator or your device is rooted.